# Get @RenderMapping to return external url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, liferay

I am using liferay and I have a spring portlet.

The view is rendered fine. I have a link to the same page - if clicked, it should perform some logic and then (conditionaly) open a new tab with a external site:

What I have so far:

```
@Component
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
...
    @RenderMapping
    public String view(Model model, PortletRequest request, PortletResponse response) throws Exception {
....
response.setProperty(ResourceResponse.HTTP_STATUS_CODE, String.valueOf(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY));
final String redirect = "https://......";
response.setProperty("Location", redirect);
            return "redirect:" + redirect;
.....
```

It does open a new tab, but it does not leave the portal context. It wont open the new location.
Any hints?

Comment: Any reason for having `PortletRequest` instead of `HttpServletResponse`?

Comment: Thx! I have access to HttpServletResponse. So I did test httpServletResponse.sendRedirect(redirect), but the method view still returns String. It didn't work. I have one use case in which I have to return a relative path. Switching the return Class to HttpServletResponse didn't work - it just showed a empty page.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have access to  try the following:

```java
@RenderMapping
public String view(Model model, PortletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    final String redirect = "https://......";
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    response.setHeader("Location", redirect);
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rendering a portlet *always* renders part of a page in a portal, thus you won't have access to the original `HttpServletResponse` without trickery. And even if you get access, the response might already be committed, the portal engine might have decided to deliver your content asynchronously - you're well shielded from the actual result. in short: you can't really think along any HTTP games.

You have a couple of other options though:

- render JS that does the redirect
- move your code to the portlet's Action phase, where state updates are expected (render phase is supposed to render, not to change state or make such decisions) - in the action phase you could issue a redirect, but it'll be hard to conditionally do so for opening in a new tab
- move your code to the portlet's resource phase, trigger it asynchronously and decide in the frontend if you want to open a new tab or not, based on the return you get.
- move your code to a REST service (continue as in the resource phase bullet point above)